# Word 365: What causes 'straight' quotes to be changed to 'smart' quotes en masse? How to prevent?

Tags: microsoft-word-365, smart-quotes

In my job, Word documents often contain XML or CSV snippets.  In these, needless to say, the quotation marks need to stay 'straight'.  Normally I can paste the snippets in and the quotes will remain 'straight' as they were originally.

However, every now and again I find that, for no apparent reason, all these quotes that were 'straight' in my document have magically become 'smart' quotes, throughout the document, without me doing anything or being immediately aware.

My questions are:

- What triggers Word to do this?
- How can I prevent it from happening, without disabling 'smart' quotes completely?

Comment: You don't want to hear this, but in my experience the only sure way to keep Word from messing with quotes is to disable in the Proofing settings on the AutoFormat tab the options "Replace - Straight quotes with smart quotes".  And when you get a document last edited (or created) by someone else check this setting again, because it seems Word saves a lot of the last-used settings in the document itself and this may be one of them.

Comment: See https://www.officetooltips.com/office_365/tips/setting_autocorrect_options.html to turn Autocorrect and/or specific features on or off.

Comment: @Tonny Does this mean the AutoFormat tab controls things that Word does randomly behind my back?  Does Word do any of the other things on that tab randomly behind my back?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm a little puzzled about why you've pointed me here.  Tonny's comment suggests it's the AutoFormat tab I need, but that page seems to talk only about things that happen _as you type_.

Comment: @Stewart It is supposed to only do things "as you type", but I have the distinct impression that sometimes it considers a Paste or Drag'n'Drop operation as "typing" too. Which can seriously mess things up. I've never been able to reliably reproduce it, but I have seen enough weird things happening to not trust the AutoCorrect/Format features anymore. Editing a document multiple times alternating both Word and its  web-version (e.g a document in Sharepoint) also seems sometimes to mess things up.

Comment: @Tonny My question is about existing straight quotes being _later_ mangled by Word.  Not when typed or when pasted in.

Comment: @Stewart, "autocorrect" means making changes *for* you, whether immediately or later. The word "auto" meaning by itself, without your request to do so (e.g., hitting F7).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Where do you get that definition from?  Furthermore, whatever "autocorrect" means, "AutoCorrect" has always to me meant the feature that makes corrections as you type, not later.  Moreover, typographical tweaks such as smart quotes aren't on the "AutoCorrect" tab as I look, but on "AutoFormat" and "AutoFormat As You Type".